# Cannot access GAC from C# code

Tags: c#, windows-server-2003, gac

I have a third-party .net DLL that I installed and registered, and appears in the GAC (c:\windows\assembly).  I am able to successfully access the GAL in my development and my test environments, but not in production.

My web service is written in C#.Net, .Net 2.0 framework.  I can only assume that the problem occurs during the line where Assembly.LoadWithPartialName() is called

My development environment is Windows XP Pro; test is Windows Server 2003; and production is Windows Server 2003.  The only difference between test and production is that production is running over https, whereas test is in http.  Is it possible that there is some other permissions error?

I've even tried importing the DLL into the project, but with no luck of success.

Any help or insight is much appreciated!

Comment: HTTPS can lead to all kinds of weird things. You really need to make sure that's working in test as well.

Comment: Whats the error you get? also does your production have different .Net Trust permissions?

Comment: You should not use LoadWithPartialName, it is obsolete.  Use Load instead.  What's special about the server?  Is it a 64-bit machine?  Give details about the DLL as well.  And post code.

Comment: I am aware LoadWithPartialName is deprecated, but is still functional.  The server is 32bit.  The code that contains LoadWithPartialName was taken from a third-party opensource code (which I will post shortly)

Comment: Isn't the GAC always given full trust in caspol?

Comment: I've narrowed down to this exact error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8000401A): The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect.  Check the username and password. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000401A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here it is: for some reason on the server, when I installed the component, it was running as a "Server application" instead of a "library application"

Administrative Tools --> Component Services
Console Root --> Component Services --> Computers --> My Computer --> COM+ Applications

Right click the utility in question, and select properties.  Under activation, select library application; then restart.